# ASP.Net Core 2.0 IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Our Web Application has both Auth.web and WebDevX.web

Generic task - We need to update the user profile on the IDSRV outside of the IDSRV web application- that is within WebDevX.web

The User needs to be able to have the ability to resend their email confirmation generated by IDSRV from within the WebDevX.web without having to be redirected back to IDSRV.

Is it possible to call the IDSRV API Endpoint with Token issued for the Client uses ImplicitFlow (access_token) ?

Is there some other way which will allow to call the IDSRV API endpoint on behalf of the user without redirecting to the IDSRV UI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Is it possible to call the IDSRV API Endpoint with Token issued for the Client uses ImplicitFlow (access_token) ?

I suppose `IDSRV` is the identity server application which provides issue/validate the tokens, and it also provides API endpoint which allows to modify user's profile data . If that is the scenario , you can use implicit flow to acquire access token for accessing APIs which protected by Identity Server in a browser-based applications .

You can click [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#implicit) (Implicit Section)for more details and code sample . But Implicit  Flow will still redirect user to identity server's login page to sign in .

> > Is there some other way which will allow to call the IDSRV API endpoint on behalf of the user without redirecting to the IDSRV UI ?

You can use [Resource owner password Flow](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#resource-owner-password) which allows to request tokens on behalf of a user by sending the user’s name and password to the token endpoint. You can find code samples in above link . But that flow is not recommended because of security reasons .

The general recommendation is to use an interactive flow like implicit or hybrid for user authentication instead.